# React auto-render Math Latex

Tags: reactjs, mathjax, katex

I recently upgraded to ReactJS for my web application. I've been using Angular with MathJax to auto-render math TeX on a page (every time the math changes on the page, MathJax goes through the page, finds the delimiters and renders the math in place). I haven't been able to get MathJax to work with the React component lifecycle and there doesn't seem to be much information online. My previous implementation was to listen to changes to the page and call:

> MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);

How would I auto-render math TeX with React (should I even use ReactJS)? Note, my math is inline with a body of text and I want to render the math without rendering the entire text.

Thanks in advance!

Kevin

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the solution. Also make sure the MathJax script link is correct since MathJax [took down their CDN](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/).

```
class Preview extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)]);
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)]);
  }

  render () {
    var tex= this.props.name,

    if(!!tex) {
      texDisplay = "$$" + tex + "$$"
    }
    return (
      <div>The Tex!</div>
      <div>{texDisplay}</div>
    )
  }
}
```